# Are trigonometric functions with already substituted arguments (integral) treated with the chain rule, when derivating?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, logarithms, substitution

So I am left with this integral after already having done(!) one substitution before (from $dx$ to $dz$):
$$ \int \frac{32\tan(z)}{3\pi} \,dz = \int \frac{32\sin(z)}{3\pi\cos(z)} \,dz $$

and wanted to apply the substitution rule where I choose that

$$ u=\cos(z) .$$

Now I'm a little confused as to whether

$$ u'= -\sin(z)\cdot z' \ \text{or} \ u'=-\sin(z) .$$

Wolframalpha tells me the integral is

$$ -\frac{32\log(\cos(z))}{3\pi} , $$

which makes sense, IF $u'=-\sin(z)$. However, if I'd choose that $u'=-\sin(z) \cdot z'$, I would get (after cancelling out $-\sin(z)$)

$$ \int -\frac{32}{3\pi u} \,\frac{du}{-z'} = \int -\frac{32}{3\pi } \cdot \frac{-1}{uz'} \,du  $$

which would lead to a whole different integral, because the integral of $-\frac{1}{uz'}$ clearly can't be the simple $\log$ from the wolfram alpha solution... if anyone could help me out on the question which one of the derivatives is right I'd be super super thankful!!

Comment: Your $1/z$ factor seems to be spurious. You may discover how you inadvertently included it if you spell out your calculation further.

Comment: @J.G. that is just my question, if that factor is necessary. Because if I choose the first derivative and cancel the sine out, I am left with $z'$ in the denominator. Sorry I forgot to change $z$ to $z'$...

Comment: Typo in your first display, should be u = cos z. 

Instead of writing z’, write dz, and work out the rest of the calculation very carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be very careful about notation here. It helps on $u$-substitution not to think about it in terms of $u'$ or $z'$. The prime notation typically incorporates two differentials, which you want to be able to separate. Normally, $u' = \frac{du}{dz}$, but you're treating it like $du$. The integral uses differential notation, so it helps to use differential notation throughout the $u$-substitution process.

Instead of setting $u' = -\sin(z) \cdot z'$, think of it like this:

$$ u = \cos(z) $$
$$ \frac{du}{dz} = -\sin(z) . $$

Then, to transform it from a derivative to differentials, you have

$$ du = \frac{du}{dz} dz $$
$$ du = -\sin(z) dz $$
$$ dz = -\frac{1}{\sin(z)} du . $$

Going back to the integral, we can factor out $\frac{32}{3\pi}$:

$$ \int {\frac{32\sin(z)}{3\pi \cos(z)} \ dz} = \frac{32}{3\pi} \int {\frac{\sin(z)}{\cos(z)} \ dz} $$

Substitute in $u = \cos(z)$:

$$ = \frac{32}{3\pi} \int {\frac{\sin(z)}{u} \ dz} $$

Substitute in $dz = -\frac{1}{\sin(z)} du$:

$$ = \frac{32}{3\pi} \int {\frac{\sin(z)}{u} \frac{du}{-\sin(z)}} $$

Cancel out $\sin(z)$ and factor out the $-1$:

$$ = -\frac{32}{3\pi} \int {\frac{du}{u}} $$

And integrate then substitute back in $u = \cos(z)$:

$$ = -\frac{32}{3\pi} \ln(u) $$
$$ = -\frac{32}{3\pi} \ln(\cos(z)) . $$

With the right notation, the substitution process becomes a lot simpler. With slightly messier notation, it's very easy to get confused.

Comment: omg thanks!!! i got it now :))

Comment: You're very welcome, glad I could help!

Comment: just as a little follow up tho, regarding $\frac{du}{dz} = -\sin(z)$: Is the quintessence of what you're saying that the derivative of $\cos(z)$ doesn't lead to the application of the chain rule, because we're deriving after $u$ and not after $z$ (so the $\sin(z)$ gets "treated" like a generic $\sin(x)$, when derivated ?

Comment: or, in other words: $\frac{d}{dz}(cos(z)) \neq \frac{du}{dz}(cos(z))$?

Comment: Right, $\frac{d}{dz} \cos(z)$ = $\frac{du}{dz}$; $\frac{d}{dz}\cos(z) \neq \frac{du}{dz} \cos(z)$. The point of using $u = \cos(z)$ is to replace all instances of $z$ to be in terms of $u$. So, if you end up with both $u$ and $z$ in the same statement after all your substitutions, something didn't work.

Comment: I see I see! But what if let's say, we have $6\sin(2z)$. In that case, both derivatives are the same $\frac{d}{dz}(6\sin(2z))=\frac{du}{dz}(6\sin(2z))=12\sin(2z)$. Is there a way how I can see when I have to derivate or not? Basically, only whenever there are constant factors in the argument?

Comment: If you're using $u$-substitution, you always have to differentiate $u$ with respect to $z$. It's what allows you to substitute an expression in terms of $du$ into the integral to replace $dz$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int \frac{32\tan(z)}{3\pi} \,dz = \int \frac{32\left[\sin(z)\,dz\right]}{3\pi\cos(z)} $$

not $u=\cos x$
$$ u=\cos(z) \to du=-\sin z dz\to \left[\sin z \,dz\right]=-du$$
$$\frac{32}{3\pi}\int\frac{-du}{u}=-\frac{32}{3\pi}\log u+C=-\frac{32}{3\pi}\log \cos z+C$$

Comment: thank you very much! so, I can see how this works out but why does the $\sin(z)$ in the numerator disappear? If we do this we would only set $du=-du$ and substitute $\cos=u$. I don't see why $\sin(z)$ would cancel out if we do not explicitly put it into the integral. Because if we had put $\sin zdz$ into it, it would still leave $zdz$, wouldnt it?

Comment: @LinShao $\sin z \,dz$ is $-du$. I edited my answer to show it better